# How to put 0 in a column when no records were made in a day

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Im trying to fetch the numbers of customers per date for the last 28 days. I also need to get 0 if there are no customers in a certain day. However, I only know how to fetch all the dates with the records. Not the dates with 0 customers.

Instead of:

```
         date  customers
0  2022-01-02          1
1  2022-01-05          4
2  2022-01-06          1
```

I want to get

```
         date  customers
0  2022-01-01          0
1  2022-01-02          1
1  2022-01-03          0
1  2022-01-04          0
1  2022-01-05          4
2  2022-01-06          1
```

Comment: OUTER JOIN a calendar table/cte.

Comment: Please tag your DBMS product??

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way is to add a calendar table that involves all dates in a single colums and add a RIGHT OUTER JOIN ti this table.

Another way is to use a CTE (recursive or with some CROOS JOINs) to produce dynamically the calendar then join.

An old proverb says that *you only find in a database what you put in it*...

Of course the best approach from a performance point of view is the fixed calendar table